# Prove $A$ and $[0,1] \cup [2,4]$ are homemorphic if and only if

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am new to homeomorphic sets topic. I know that I have to find a bicontinuous function to prove that $A$ is homeomorphic to$ [0,1] \cup [2,3]$ if and only if it is of form $ [a,b] \cup [c,d] $. However, I don’t know how to find such a function.
$A \subset\mathbb R$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A=[a,b]\cup[c,d]$ for $a<b<c<d$, then $[a,b]\cup[c,d]\to [0,1]\cup[2,4]$ given by
$$
x\mapsto
\begin{cases}
\frac{x-a}{b-a} & \text{if $x\in [0,1]$,} \\
2+2\cdot\frac{x-c}{d-c} &\text{if $x\in[2,4]$}
\end{cases}
$$
is a homeomorphism.

Conversely, let $f\colon A\to X:=[0,1]\cup [2,4]$ be a homeomorphism. Since the union is disjoint, it follows that $A = f^{-1}([0,1]) \cup f^{-1}([2,4])$ is also a disjoint union. Since $f^{-1}$ is continuous, it maps [closed intervals to closed intervals](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Image_of_Closed_Interval_is_Closed_Interval) so that $f^{-1}([0,1])=[a,b]$ and $f^{-1}([2,4])=[c,d]$ with $a<b$ and $c<d$. In order for the union to be disjoint we must have $a<b<c<d$ or $c<d<a<b$. In any case
$$
A = [a,b] \cup [c,d]
$$
is a union of two disjoint closed intervals.

Comment: Thank you but how did you find the homeomorphism ?

Comment: By using the fact that there is a unique affine linear map $g\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ with $g(a)=a'$ and $g(b)=b'$ when $a\neq b$. It can be found by setting $g(x) = mx+c$ and solving for $m$ and $c$ or by noting that this is just scaling and translation: $g(x) = a' + (b'-a')\cdot \frac{x-a}{b-a}$.